# Entity Framework: computed field, fetched from DB only on insert... how?

Tags: entity-framework-5, calculated-columns

EF5 (code first).

I have a field CreateDate, that has a default value GETDATE(), and value set only once - on insert. If I mark property as DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed) - EF update his value on every update any other field. How I can prevent this behavior? Fetching generated value needed only after insert, but not after every update...

```
[Table("Users")]
public class EFUser
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string LoginName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string PasswordHash { get; set; }
}
```

look at example below - insert new record, and update Name field:

```
exec sp_executesql N'insert [dbo].[Users]([Name], [LoginName], [PasswordHash])
values (@0, @1, @2)
select [ID], [CreateDate]
from [dbo].[Users]
where @@ROWCOUNT > 0 and [ID] = scope_identity()',N'@0 nvarchar(50),@1 nvarchar(50),@2 nvarchar(50)',@0=N'6adbf8ac-8332-40a5-8e38-369f938867b1',@1=N'689950801',@2=N'291FD051'
go

exec sp_executesql N'update [dbo].[Users]
set [Name] = @0
where ([ID] = @1)
select [CreateDate]
from [dbo].[Users]
where @@ROWCOUNT > 0 and [ID] = @1',N'@0 nvarchar(50),@1 int',@0=N'6af61beb-2583-4f2d-8a7c-b3a03ca3b082',@1=29
go
```

First time, after insert, EF fetch back generated ID and CreateDate values - that's ok.
But after update Name... EF again fetch CreateDate, but it's not changed, never after insert.

How I can disable updating computed field value on every update?

Comment: What is the problem? Are you worried about suboptimal performance because the few bytes for the datetime are loaded over the wire after every update?

Comment: Yes. On every update SQL Server do additional select CreateDate value by ID... this is unacceptable, in the tables of millions of records, and index search with every update - it's a performance hit.

Comment: I'm not sure if it will work but you could try to put `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]` (instead of `.Computed`) on the `CreateDate` property. It might be necessary then to put the `.Identity` attribute also on the `ID` property. It's kind of misusing the `.Identity` option but I believe the main difference is that the value is only fetched after insert while `.Computed` will cause the value to load after every update.

Comment: yes, DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity works as expected, but unfortunately it changes and other aspects, such as attribute [Key] stops working as Identity, etc.

Comment: Doesn't it fix the problem with the `[Key]` attribute if you put `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]` on the `ID` property as well?